# Prove that $0 \leq u(x) \leq 1$ for every $x \in [0, a]$ if $u''(x) + u(x) (1 - u(x)) = 0$ and $u(0) = u(a) = 0$, where $a > 0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Let $a$ be a positive number. Suppose that $u$: $[0, a] \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function, that $u(0) = u(a) = 0$, that the first- and second-order derivatives of $u$ are continuous in $(0, a)$, and that  $u''(x) + u(x) (1 - u(x)) = 0$ for every $x \in (0, a)$. Prove that $0 \leq u(x) \leq 1$ for every $x \in [0, a]$.

One part is easy. Assume on the contrary that $u(t_0) > 1$ for some $t_0 \in [0, a]$. Since $u$ is continuous, its maximum exists. There exists some $t_1 \in [0, a]$ such that $u(t_1) \geq u(x)$ for every $x \in [0, a]$. Then $u(t_1) \geq u(t_0) > 1$ and by calculus, $u''(t_1) \leq 0$ (note that $t_1$ cannot be $0$ or $a$). Then
$$
0 = u''(t_1) + u(t_1) (1 - u(t_1)) < 0,
$$
a contradiction.

The other part does not seem to be easy, however. I tried to do it by mimicking the way in which I solved the part above, but I did not get a contradiction.

---

### The reason for which I raised the question:

I take a course in partial differential equations. The instructor uses [the second edition of *An Introduction to Nonlinear Partial Differential Equations* by J. David Logan](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470225955) as the textbook. I am actually concerned about the existence of the solution to some boundary value problem. Here is the context. $D$ is an open, bounded, connected subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. The operator $L$ is "uniformly elliptic" in $D$, which means that $L$ is of the form
$$
Lu := \sum_{1 \leq i,j \leq n} {a_{i,j} (x) \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}} + \sum_{1 \leq j \leq n} {b_j (x) \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_j}},
$$
where the coefficients $a_{i,j}$ and $b_j$ are continuously differentiable functions on $D$ that are continuous on $D$, and that there exists a positive number $\mu$ such that
$$
\sum_{1 \leq i,j \leq n} {a_{i,j} (x) \xi_i \xi_j} \geq \mu \sum_{1 \leq j \leq n} {\xi_j^2}
$$
for every $x \in D$ and $\xi_j \in \mathbb{R}$.

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

[image: image 3]

[image: image 4]

[image: image 5]

(Note that there are typos in (7.2.7) and (7.2.8); $(x, y)$, instead of $x$, should be used.)

The example intends to demonstrate how the existence theorem is used. The author tries to find an upper solution $\overline{u}$, and a lower solution $\underline{u}$ that is not greater than $\overline{u}$. I do not understand why the author says "Then $\overline{u}(x) \geq 0$ on $\partial D$ and $-\Delta \overline{u} = -{\overline{u}}'' = \overline{u} (1 - \overline{u}) \geq 0$." That $\overline{u} \leq 1$ has been justified above, but the other part has not.

After reading your replies, I guess that the author makes a mistake here. If so, what should I do in order to amend the demonstration?

Comment: Just do the same thing. Suppose there is $t_0\in(0,1)$ such that $u(t_0)<0$. Then $\min u(t)<0$.

Comment: @xpaul It doesn't work the same. You don't get a contradiction.

Comment: The other part cannot be proved because it is false. If $|u|\ll 1$, the ODE can be approximated by $u''+u=0$. If $a=\pi$, the solution $u(x)=-\epsilon\sin x$ $(0<\epsilon\ll 1)$ satisfies $u(0)=u(a)=0$ and $u(x)<0$ if $x\in(0,a)$.